# How to use folderbrowser dialog box in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I need  to add FolderBrowserDialog in my WPF application.
I know one way is add to `System.Windows.Forms.dll`, but that way is not working properly.

My XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="Sample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        WindowState="Normal"
        ResizeMode="NoResize"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="600">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Height="30" width="80" Name="TextBox1"/>
        <Button Height="50" Width="50" Content="Browse" Click="btn_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

My code-behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace Sample
{
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            FolderBrowserDialog folderDialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
            folderDialog.SelectedPath = "C:\\";

            DialogResult result = folderDialog.ShowDialog();
            if (result.ToString() == "OK") 
                textBox1.Text = folderDialog.SelectedPath;
         }
    }
}
```

I added `System.Windows.Forms.dll` in my dependencies. After added `System.Windows.Forms.dll`, the `FolderBrowserDialog` class is working properly, but `InitializeComponent();` is showing an error:

> InitializeComponent does not exist in the current context

Comment: You have to fully qualify the Winforms types e.g. `System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog `. Important: `FolderBrowserDialog` implements `IDisposable`. So when using a local variable of type `FolderBrowserDialog` make sure it is used inside a `using` block (or `finally`). If using an instance member of type `FolderBrowserDialog` then also let the surrounding type implement `IDisposable`.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to removed `using System.Windows.Forms;` from the top of your code-behind and replace it with `using System.Windows;`.

Having the former line is causing the your `Window` to be compiled as a `System.Windows.Forms.Window` (a WinForms window), instead of a `System.Window.Window` (a WPF window.

You will then need to put the full namespace in your type declarations, so your code will become:

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    using (System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog folderDialog = new System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog())
    {
        folderDialog.SelectedPath = "C:\\";

        System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult result = folderDialog.ShowDialog();
        if (result.ToString() == "OK")
            textBox1.Text = folderDialog.SelectedPath;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that `FolderBrowserDialog` implements `IDisposable`.

Comment: @BionicCode Good catch, I added the appropriate `using` block.

Comment: I removed System.Windows.Forms, then added System.Windows.Forms.Window but again build err coming.                                                                                
 
Error CS0234 The type or namespace name 'Window' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows.Forms' (are you missing an assembly reference?) FileOpenDialog C:\Users\SSC_03\source\repos\FileOpenDialog\FileOpenDialog\MainWindow.xaml.cs 15 Active

Comment: @karthick19892089 Do you have the code `System.Windows.Forms.Window` somewhere now? Because you shouldn't. You might need to edit your question to show the current code you have.

Comment: @karthick19892089 You messed it up. Just remove `using System.Windows.Forms`. **Don't add anything else here**. Because you've added `System.Windows.Forms.Window` you created an ambiguity with the `System.Windows` namespace as both contain a `Window` class. WPF needs to reference `System.Windows.Windows`. Nobody told you to add this namespace. This answer is perfect. Use this solution. No need to import any 3rd party library like FolderBrowserDialogEx. Note that this is not a .NET library. It's an unnecessary dependency at this point. Just use the .NET dialog as shown in this answer.

Comment: @BionicCode An ambiguous type match was my first thought too, until I remembered that there *is no* `System.Windows.Forms.Window` class- WinForms uses `System.Windows.Forms.Form`.

Comment: @Keith Stein Yes indeed, that's true. This explains the error even more.Adding this nonexistent namespace prevents the code from compiling. Compiler fails to resolve it and shows the reference not found error which asks to add the reference to the DLL that contains this namespace. The editor must at least show squiggles to indicate this error. He must have ignored this hint. But whatever he added, he must remove it anyway. I really wonder what leads him to add this namespace and ignoring the Intellisense error.

Answer (score 0):

WPF doesnt have a native FolderBrowserDialog control. Baffling, I know.

You can use the winforms version as shown above or you can try a 3rd party control like ookii.dialogs

http://www.ookii.org/software/dialogs/

Comment: Thanks. how to integrate with wpf project

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Try these using statements:</strike>

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using FolderBrowserDialog = System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog;
```

Try this as your class

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using FolderBrowserDialog = System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog;

namespace Sample
{
     public partial class MainWindow : Window
     {
          public MainWindow()
          {
               InitializeComponent();
          }

          public string FolderPath { get; set; } = string.Empty;

          public string OpenFolderTitle { get; set; } = string.Empty;

          private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
          {
               ShowFolderPathEditWindow();
          }

          private void ShowFolderPathEditWindow()
          {
               string defaultFolderPath = string.IsNullOrEmpty(FolderPath) ? Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) : FolderPath;
               string folderPath = ShowFolderBrowserDialog(defaultFolderPath);
               bool TFfolderPath = string.IsNullOrEmpty(folderPath) | string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace;

               FolderPath = TFfolderPath switch { true => string.Empty, false => folderPath };
          }

          private string ShowFolderBrowserDialog(string defaultFolderPath)
          {
               FolderBrowserDialog folderBrowserDialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();

               folderBrowserDialog.Description = OpenFolderTitle;
               folderBrowserDialog.ShowNewFolderButton = true;
               folderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath = defaultFolderPath;
               folderBrowserDialog.ShowDialog();
               return folderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath;
          }
     }
}
```

You can bind the TextBox's Text property to FolderPath if you want to control the folder location.

Answer (score 0):

> I got the answer. When i use folderbrowserdialog box in wpf. i need to download FolderBrowserDialogEx.dll in ManageNuGetPackage. after download the package. FolderBrowserDialog box working fine. Try this.

Comment: The answer of @Keith Stein is perfect. Use this solution. No need to import any 3rd party library like FolderBrowserDialogEx. Note that this is not a .NET library. It's an unnecessary dependency at this point. Just use the .NET dialog as shown in [Keith's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61810058/3141792) answer.